# Java: Receiving platform independent TCP streams

Tags: java, sockets, networking, network-protocols

I want to build a Java server that accepts TCP streams that are completely platform independent, so that the client could be written in any other language like C++, PHP, ActionScript or anything else.

However, when I want to write different primitives to the stream like int, short etc. I must take care for the right integer length and if the integer is signed or unsigned. This is a problem, because the integer byte length varies strongly across different platforms, e.g. PHP integers have different size on 32 and 64 bit machines.

For this reason it might be reasonable to send only text and not integer values, because every machine interprets text in the same way if the text uses the same char set and byte order. Hence, the server can only use DataInputStream.readUTF() if it should read platform independent data.

I'm not sure if my arguments are correct, but if I should be wrong please correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can send text, you shouldn't use writeUTF/readUTF as this is a specific format. i.e. an unsigned `short` length followed by the UTF characters.

The reason text can be used is because you expect to parse each byte at a time, you can do exactly the same with binary (and it's is usually much faster)

The biggest difference is that text is much easier to read and debug.  For this reason alone I suggest making your first protocol text based.  I would only suggest doing binary protocols when you are much more confident you can debug protocol errors.

Comment: Thank you. Well, I don't have any experience with that, hence it would
be sufficient for the start to understand the basics of sending platform independent TCP streams. 

So if I can't use `readUTF(`) to remain platform independent I can only make use of low-level, byte-oriented methods and read one byte after the other like this:

`ByteArrayOutputStream txtMessage = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   int next;
   while ((next = in.read()) != END) {
  // .......
      txtMessage.write(next); 
}
// Then convert txtMessage to string and parse it to extract data.`

Comment: On the client (if it is a Java client) I have to convert the string to a byte array and then just use `write()` to write the byte array to the output stream. Is this approach basically ok?

Comment: That is basically ok, but could be hard work.  I would consider using PrintWriter with OutputStreamWriter for writing and and Scanner or BufferedReader with InputStreamReader.  In both cases I would set the CHarset to something like `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`

Comment: Thanks. Am I right in assuming that an UTF-8 char can fit in a byte chunk, but doesn't have to, because UTF-8 chars can use multiple bytes for non-ASCII characters? Hence, only ASCII can ensure that one char fits into one byte, which eliminates any trouble with byte orders.

Comment: @user1812379 Technically US-ASCII is 7-bit,  You can assume ISO-8859-1 which is 8-bit characters 0-255 have a one to one mapping. ;)  Or you can give a technical name to dropping characters > 255 ;)

Answer (score 1):

Even DataInputStream.readUTF() is not an universal feature. It uses rather complex encoding.

Find data format that already has client libraries for most popular languages, e.g. [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) or  [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/).

Comment: This means that I can forget all specialized versions of `write()` like `writeInt()`, `writeChar()` etc. and only use simple `OutputStream.write()` that writes pure bytes to the stream?

Comment: Not so. Instead of using methods of DataInputStream, which is absent in other languages, use methods of selected universal library, which have counterparts in other languages, so you easily can maintain correctness of coding and decoding modules.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't it possible to write pure ASCII or UTF-8 text to an output stream by using only Java Standard libraries?

Comment: it is possible, but then client and server programmers have to set additional protocol rules like allowed string delimeters, number representation etc, and to support that rules, for each language a library should be created. So why not to take an existing library, which is optimized and debugged.

Comment: Thanks. Well, it's just for learning purposes to understand the basics. Number representation can be complex, that's why I want to use only text. The message uses some char as delimiter, maybe 
"%". Because a char isn't always represented by a byte depending on the encoding that is used, I must make sure that the text is encoded the same way on both endpoints. The documentation of `DataOutputStream` says: "...lets an application write primitive 
Java data types to an output stream in a portable way." What does "portable" here mean? Portable between JVMs on different operating systems?

Comment: Portable means that the data format is carefully described, is not going to change, and can be implemented in other languages.

Comment: OK. I haven't yet understood how to find out which streams can be used for platform independent TCP communication and which not. All those streams are wrapped around InputStream and OutputStream, but I don't know if I have to go to that low level.