# Protocol for platform independent socket communication

Tags: java, c++, sockets, networking, tcp

I'm trying to understand how platform independent socket communication works, because I would like to share socket data between a Java server and some native Unix and Windows clients. Sockets are platform independent by design, but the data representation is machine-related, hence it is advantageous if the TCP data abstracts the real data format, because a data format that is supported on one system doesn't have to be necessarily supported on another.

For example if I want to send an unsigned int value from a C++ client program to a Java server I must tell the server that this number should be interpreted as a negative integer. How does this kind of abstraction work? With my limited knowledge I would just send a number as text and then append some kind of unique character sequence that tells the receiver what kind of data he received, but I don't know if this is a viable approach.

To be a bit more concrete: I would like to send messages that contain the following content:

1. At the beginning of the message some kind of short signal or command
   so that the receiver exactly knows what to do with the data that will follow.
2. Then some textual content of arbitrary length.
3. Followed by a number, which can be also text, but should be
   interpreted separately.
4. At the end maybe a mark that tells the server that the message ends
   here.

TCP processes the data in byte chunks. Does this mean when I write an UTF-8 encoded char in one byte that this char is interpreted in the same way on different machines if the client machines take Java's big endian byte order into account? Thanks for any input and help.

Comment: "Sockets are platform independent by design, but the data representation is machine-related" <-- only if you choose so! Just pick a data format which doesn't have this problem -- as @ctn says, you can pick JSON or protobuf. Problem solved.

Comment: Protobuf was what I was thinking when I read this.

Comment: " I would just send a number as text and then append some kind of unique character sequence that tells the receiver what kind of data he received"  **Gross!**

Comment: Duplicate of [Java: Receiving platform independent TCP streams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042731/java-receiving-platform-independent-tcp-streams)

Comment: Thanks. I don't have a clue of this topic, but maybe sending an XML string could also be an option? Is there any recommendable book that could help me to get a deeper understanding of this issue?

Comment: Don't keep asking the same question.

Comment: Sorry. I thought my other question was not precise enough.

Comment: "Does this mean when I write an UTF-8 encoded char in one byte that this char is interpreted in the same way on different machines"  The receiver will get the same byte (i.e. the number).  What they do with it (e.g. convert to a character) is another matter.

Answer (score 0):

Sockets are independent but not the data transmitted in (Types length, byte order, String encoding,  ...)

Look at [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org), [Protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) or [Avro](https://avro.apache.org/) if you want to send binary data with cross-languages and cross-platform functionnalities

Comment: I know those problems, but I didn't want to use a library, because I want to understand how this works. For test purposes I just want to send some simple data.